# c++ timing same loop gives different results

Tags: c++, timing, c++-chrono

Can someone explain why running this code multiple times gives very variable results?
Unless I did something wrong, it should measure the time my system (MacOSX Sierra, Xcoe9.2) takes to run an empty for loop 1000 times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void printstuff (){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    //empty loop
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto time1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    printstuff();
    auto time2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time2 - time1).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to measure time, you should measure something last is not optimized away.

Comment: could you elaborate on "measure something last is not optimized away"?

Comment: It's the answer. The compiler removes the empty loop. there are other issues with this kind of instrumented profiles as well. Use perf, papi, or vtune (free now I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you compiling that code? Which flags are you using?

If you are using any level of optimization (using one of the optimization flags, see for example: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html for gcc) then the function printstuff() is compiled to zero instructions, as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/gXq-mG

If you are not using any optimization flag, that loop will still execute too fast for you to measure anything (you are most likely measuring noise).

If you want to benchmark code I would recommend you [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

Comment: I am learning c++ and I just wanted to check the difference in timing when declaring printstuff as ""inline". It looks like I am missing some details on optimization flags. I will have a look at the links you posted.

Comment: in the godbolt link you sent if I add    std::cout<<0<<std::endl;  it's compiled to some instructions but still get different timing in the original code.

Comment: If you add that, then you will be measuring the time it takes to print 0 one thousand times. As I suggested, Google Benchmark is a very good library to do benchmarks of your code.